# Downsample large raster without reprojecting first

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution, resampling

How can I downsample a large TIFF (raster) which is projected in decimal degrees without first having to reproject it to meters. I know that in meters the resolution is 3cm and I want to downsample to 50cm.

[image: Raster properties]

Comment: I've got to frame challenge here. Reprojecting *is* resampling. You'll get far better data fidelity if you reproject *then* generalize than if you generalize then resample.

Comment: What do you mean by generlize

Comment: 290:1 resampling